# Infinity loop on load api data with useReducer and useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to load the data from my backend API, into my component using the useReducer() hook via a useContext().

However, when running in the browser, this starts an infinite loop.

I'm not sure because I'm new to React, I think the loop is due to useEffect() which executes the dispatch to make the API call, causing the component to be updated, which in turn re-executes the useEffect ().

I tried with a useCallback, but without much change.

Voici le clientContext.js :

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';
import api from '../api';

// Create context
const ClientContext = createContext(null);

const initialState = {
  clients: [],
  client: {},
};

const clientReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_CLIENTS':
      return { ...state, clients: action.payload };
      //..... Other case .....
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


// Create Provider for the context
export const ClientProvider = ({ children }) => {
  
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(clientReducer, initialState);

  const getClients = async () => {
    let clients = await api.get('/clients')
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_CLIENTS', payload: clients });
  }

  return (
    <ClientContext.Provider value={{ state, getClients }}>
      {children}
    </ClientContext.Provider>
  );
};


export const useClientContext = () => {
  return useContext(ClientContext);
};
```

clientContextComponent.js (child who load data)

```
//import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import { useClientContext } from "../../hooks/clientContext"
import { useEffect } from "react";

const ClientContextComponent = () => {

    const {state, getClients} = useClientContext()

    useEffect(() => {
      getClients()
    }, [getClients]);

    console.log(state)

    return (
      <div>
        {/* {JSON.stringify(state)} */}
      </div>
        // <Outlet context={state.clients}/>
    )
}
export default ClientContextComponent;
```

MainContent.js (Parent)

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ClientProvider } from '../hooks/clientContext';
import ClientContextComponent from './context/clientContextComponent';
const MainContent = () => {

  const location = useLocation()
  return (
    <ClientProvider>
        <div className="flex-1 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto p-4">
          {/* Main content of your dashboard */}

          { location.pathname === '/dashboard/clients'? <ClientContextComponent/>: ''}
        </div>
    </ClientProvider>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

I have seen a lot of examples, making an API call and dispatcher in useEffect(), and not making an API call in the Context file, but I find that less readable.

If you have anything that could put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getClients` in the useEffect where it is also a dependency. When that effect runs `getClients` fetches the data which then sets the state in `ClientContext` causing that component to re-render and the effect to run again...and the cycle continues.

If you want this to run once on mount, leave the dependency array empty.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      getClients()
    }, []);
```

See React's documentation for more information: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#